# How to make a script that installs nodejs on any OS

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I have been trying to make a script in bash on how to install node.js on any Operating system. I have tried using docker, but it seems to not work. Is there a better method. I would appreciate it if you could. I would like it so that the script installs it for all users, meaning superuser permissions/superuser shell is not required. Here is small script that I borrowed that checks if you have nodejs installed

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f tt
echo `which node` > tt
value=`ls -lrt tt | awk '{print $5}'`
if [ $value == 1 ]
then
  rm tt
  echo "nodejs is not installed. Now installing."
  #installing code
else
  rm tt
  echo "installed"
fi
```

Can someone please help me, I hope I have provided enough details, and please comment if you need more. Have a great day.

Comment: all os includes windows ? sunos ? macos ? ubuntu ? etc ? are you gonna try to build it first ?

Comment: yes, as many OS as possible. main 3 are windows mac and linux for now.

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO

Comment: im not asking for an entire script, that would be ridiculous. And I do not want it to seem that way at all. I was asking if there's a method that installs for every platform. I don't want it to seem like I'm asking you to write it. I'm merely asking for startagys to do this. Sorry if this came out wrong @thatotherguy.

Comment: Just wondering: What is the point of having a *bash* script installer on Windows? Now the user has to install bash first manually, so that node can be installed automatically.

Comment: I mean, not bash. Just shell script